# 2pc - XA/Distributed Transaction Coordinator Implementation

Tags: microservices, distributed-transactions, xa, transactionmanager, 2phase-commit

I have watch several of article about XA/Distributed Transaction Coordinator, many of them just mentioned that a DBMS must explicitly support XA in order to run. They also talk about how a Distributed Transaction Coordinator works. However, after reading a lot of these information, yes, I know what a DTC does, but I don't even know how to start.

Have looking so long but I don't find a out of box DTC. Do we need to implement DTC by ourselves? Isn't there any existing usable DTC framework?

---

Some related StackOverflow post:

[How do two-phase commits prevent last-second failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171876/how-do-two-phase-commits-prevent-last-second-failure)

[2PC distributed transactions across many microservices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382918/2pc-distributed-transactions-across-many-microservices)

[How to process distributed transaction within postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109362/how-to-process-distributed-transaction-within-postgresql)

Comment: Yes, you would usually use an existing implementation. For example, this is often implemented in Java application servers. The second link in your question refers to [LIXA](https://www.tiian.org/lixa/), an open source, multi-language implementation. What platform are you targeting?

Comment: @Tim Moore I am targeting at .NET CORE on Linux

Comment: I would recommend tagging your question as such so that it will be seen by someone who can answer for that platform.